# Merge a function with an object with jQuery extend method, why's only function is returned?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
var object1 = function() {};
var object2 = {prop: "hello"};
$.extend(object1, object2)
```

In Chrome developer console, when type `object1`, only the function is returned. But I can type `object1.prop`. Why's that?

Comment: If by “only the function is returned” you mean that it doesn’t have a `prop` property, well… it apparently does. If this is about the function showing up as just `function () {}` in the console, the answer is that functions aren’t formatted in a way that shows their properties in your console.

Comment: Hi @Ryan O'Hara, thanks for the comment. Yes, my question is in regards to the console. Also why type typeof(object1), it returns 'function'

Comment: As Macmee wrote, `$.extend` puts the properties of `object2` on `object1`. It remains a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `extend` method from the [jquery doc](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/):

> Description: Merge the contents of two or more objects together into
>   the first object.

When you do this:

```
$.extend(object1, object2)
```

what you're saying is "take the properties of `object2` (`prop = "hello"`) and slap them onto `object1`. Therefore what you're doing is giving `object1` a property called `prop`.

so another example:

```
// this object
var colours = { red: 1, green: 2, blue: 3 };

// will be merged into this one below
var people = { bob: 4, joe: 5 };

// like this!
$.extend(people, colours);

console.log(people);

// prints { red: 1, green: 2, blue: 3, bob: 4, joe: 5 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var object1 = function() {};
var object2 = {prop: "hello"};
merged = $.extend(object1, object2)
// function() {}
merged.prop
// "hello"
```

function with prop be returned;